# Why is my N-Queens program hanging at filled=3, row=4, and col=7/8?

Tags: c++, stack, n-queens

So I'm working on an N-Queens problem in C++ that requires me to use stacks for back-tracking. So far, I have the code shown below, and it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. The values keep getting stuck at:
row: 4
col: 7
col: 8
filled: 3
Basically, all queen characters denoted by "1" in the board array have to be placed so that there are no conflicts (any queen can move diagonally or horizontally without running into another queen). 
Can someone help me figure out what's causing it to hang? Sorry if I'm missing any information, this is my first post here.

*edit1: The hanging behavior occurs when the board looks like the one below. So the main problem is after the 4th queen is placed when trying to place the 5th.

```
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stack> 
using namespace std;

bool isSafe(int board[8][8], int row, int col);

int main(){
int board[8][8];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        board[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

int row = 0, col = 0, filled = 0;

stack <int> rowStack;
stack <int> colStack;

rowStack.push(row);
colStack.push(col);

board[row][col] = 1;
row++;

while(filled < 7){
    if(isSafe(board,row,col)){
        //if the position is safe, place a queen at row, col and push them to each stack
        filled++;
        rowStack.push(row);
        colStack.push(col);
        board[row][col] = 1;
        //if board has all queens placed on it, print the contents
        if(filled > 8){
            for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
                    cout<<board[i][j]<<" ";
                    cout<<endl;
                }
            }
            return 0;
            }
            cout<<"Filled: "<<filled<<endl;
        row++;
        cout<<"Row: "<<row<<endl;
    }
    else{
    col++;
      cout<<"Column: "<<col<<endl;
    }
    if(col > 7){
        row = rowStack.top();
        rowStack.pop();
        col = colStack.top();
        colStack.pop();
        board[row][col] = 0; //backtracking step
        filled--;
    }
}
return 0;
}

bool isSafe(int board[8][8], int row, int col){

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(board[row][i]==1 || board[i][col]==1) 
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; (row - i)>=0 && (col-i) >= 0; i++){
        if(board[row-i][col-i]==1) 
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; (row - i)<=8 && (col-i) >= 0; i++){
        if(board[row+i][col+i]==1) 
        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey chip, its generally preferable to have a very minimal example for stack overflow, and to not necessarily look for holisitic "why doesn't it work". Your post would benefit from narrowing down the exact behavior in question. It would also be helpful if you explained the "hang" behavior. 
I will also mention that you might want to use codereview.stackexchange.com for general feedback.

Comment: Hint:  print out the board at each move or before the move where it crashes.

Comment: In your backtracking step `if (col > 7) { ... }`, you go to the position of the last queen and remove it. However, then your `while(filled < 7) { ... }` loop restarts and places the queen at the exact same place again. Backtracking does not work if you do the same thing over and over again - you need to do something different.

Answer (score -1):

Again, I will reiterate that debugging more than a single line of code starts to get outside of scope for stackoverflow.

Col does not reset when you place a queen, so you are ignoring potential valid squares earlier in the row.

There are also other bugs, and some parts that could be improved. For example you might prefer to memset your 2d array rather than iterate and each index and do a lot of unecessary math.

Comment: I believe the scope for stack overflow is only one that you place on it. It's a place to ask questions for potential answers, regardless of how small or obvious. There cannot be valid squares earlier in the row, since two queens cannot be in the same row. That is the kind of conflict that I originally explained. Of course there are parts that can be improved, as this is a brute-force implementation that I have attempted. It's not supposed to be optimized; I am just trying to get it to work for now.

Comment: Stack overflow does have a few guidelines/ advice on asking questions which you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also, I will say, there can be valid squares earlier in the row. For example in your pasted output you can see one such example. the 3rd column on the 5th row is a place that is "safe" for a queen, but your implementation has already moved forward beyond that column and has no process to check if that is a valid location.

Comment: I'm also not advising that you modify your solution to make it more optimized. In directing you to code review I am just pointing out that it is also valuable to be concerned about code quality, design principles.  CR.SE is a great network of individuals that regularly give industry quality review.